# Get list item dynamically in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have some loop on the page and need list item depending from loop number.

When I call:

```
{{ mylist.1 }}
{{ mylist.2 }}
{{ mylist.3 }}
```

all works fine but what I really need is something like:

```
{% for x in somenumber|MyCustomRangeTag %}
    {{ mylist.x }}
{% endfor %}
```

MyCustomRangeTag gives me Python `range()` it works and I already have `x` as number. So `x` is 1, 2, 3 etc. depending from loop number.
Is this possible and how?

Comment: can you just pass the values you need in the view? if you know the range before hand why not just pass the exact values you are trying to display?

Comment: No, I can't in this case. It's hard coded custom shopping cart page and all this is a part of the some nested forms.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not possible directly because Django thinks that `"x"` is the key to lookup in `mylist` - instead of *the value* of x. So, when `x = 5`, Django tries to look up `mylist["x"]` instead of `mylist[5]`.

Use the following filter as workaround:

```
@register.filter
def lookup(d, key):
    return d[key]
```

and use it like

```
{{ mylist|lookup:x }}
```

Comment: What if the output of `{{ mylist|lookup:x }}` is an object and I further need to access something? Something like `mylist.1.first_name`

Comment: @zengr Try `{% with lookup_result=mylist|lookup:x %}{{lookup_result.first_name}}{% endwith %}`.

Answer (score 5):

I notice that @e-satis mentioned it, but I think the built-in slice template tag deserves some love.

```
{{ item | slice:"2" }} #gets the third element of the list
```

Comment: this may have worked previously but gave some funky results when I gave it a shot with django 1.5

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `{{ some_list|slice:":2" }}` did the trick --https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Comment: @Hayden I believe that only gets the first two elements of the list? I updated the code to fix the filter syntax.

Comment: This gets the third element of the list, but still doesn't work to get an element from a list when the index you want to use is stored in a var

Comment: `{% with "2" as var %} {{ mylist | slice: var }} {% endwith %}`

Answer (score 5):

The slice tag in Django templates may use python's slicing code, but the syntax is unmistakably different. For instance, if you wanted to get an element of a sequence with a variable, in python you'd write something similar to the following:

```
>>>mylist = ["0th Element", "1th Element"]
>>>zero, one = 0, 1
>>>mylist[zero]
"0th Element"
>>>mylist[one]
"1th Element"
```

Using this syntax with the Django slice template tag will return a sliced list in every case, of dubious utility for getting an item of known index:

```
{% with "0" as zero %}
{% with "1" as one %}
{% with "2" as two %}

{{mylist|slice:zero}} {{mylist|slice:one}} {{mylist|slice:two}}

{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Renders to the html:

```
[] ["0th Element"] ["0th Element", "1th Element"]
```

Note the differences: you are getting the result of `mylist[:x]` instead of `mylist[x]`.

Django provides enough tools to work around this. The first trick is to use explicit slices like `0:1` for your indices, and then `|join:""` the resultant list into a single element. Like so:

```
{% with "0:1" as zero %}
{{mylist|slice:zero|join:""}}
{% endwith %}
```

Yields:

```
0th Element
```

This comes in particularly handy if you need to access a parent loop's index when dealing with an iterable inside a child loop:

```
{% for parent in parent_loop %}
    {% cycle "0:1" "1:2" "2:3" as parent_loop_index silent %}
    {% for child in child_loop %}
        {{child|slice:parent_loop_index|join:""}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Completed with nothing but stock parts, although I don't think Django has implemented achievements yet.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you can't just do:

```
{% for item in mylist %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

With the slice filter, you can even do some customisation.

Comment: I think you mean to have `{{ item }}` on the second line. It's also worth noting here that you could use `{{ forloop.counter }}` within the loop if you need an index for some reason.

Comment: Haha, no worries. Thanks for the tip, though. I actually wasn't intimidated by your rep, I just forgot we are able to edit answers. This will inspire me when I feel shy in the future, though.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
{% for 1,2,3 in mylist %}
# do stuff
```

Just don't use brackets around 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Please *don't*. Arbitrary dictionary lookups have not been implemented by Django, but for *good* reasons.

The main reason not to do this, is that logic in the template that needs this, is often *business logic*. Such logic does *not* belong to the template, but should be moved to the view.

Another problem is that Django's template engine is not very efficient: it requires a lot of context resolutions, and rendering logic, meaning that such dictionary lookups are thus not "for free", these will slow down rendering, especially if it is done in a loop.

Often it will also require resolving the variable that is the key, and this can make debugging more *tricky*, since it is possible that the result of the context resolution is not what one would expect. For example if the variable is not found, it will use the [**`string_if_invalid`** value <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#variables), which is not per se what one might intend, and thus the behavior could produce a result, but a wrong result.

Finally if an error occurs, it makes debugging harder, and if something goes wrong, it is possible that this is passed *silently*, whereas it is often better that in case something fails, it is at least logged somewhere.

If you need to perform arbitrary *subscripting* or attribute lookups, that means you should move the logic from the template to the *view*. Indeed, in that case you prepare the data in the view, for example here with:

```
def my_view(request):
    my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']
    result = [my_list[k] for k in range(1, some_number)]
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'result': result})
```

and thus then process `result` in the template, not the logic with *`my_list`*.