# How to achieve list Iteration in django template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get list item dynamically in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates)

How to get list items with variable counter. The aim is to get the so item instead of list

not like this

```
{% for item in listModels %} 
 {{ item | safe }} 

{% endfor %}
```

so work

```
{% for i in listModels|length|get_range %} // get size list 

 {{ listModels.i | safe }}

{% endfor %}
```

do not work

```
{% for i in listModels|length|get_range %} // get size list 

 {{ listModels.i | safe }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django templates will not allow you to do this.  I'm not going to lecture you on keeping your logic out of your templates, because I think it's a stylistic choice.  But understand that this is the easiest way.  If you need to use the index, you can access it as a `forloop` property, as explained in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

If you really want variable indexing, you could make your own custom template tag to do it.  But, in this case, I suggest you use a more powerful templating language, like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), instead of torturing the Django templating language.

Comment: The question is, should warped list with two first round the two list are the same number of elements

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but if you're saying you have two lists you want to iterate over in tandem, then I suggest using ``zip`` to merge them into one list of tuples.

Comment: It's a built-in function, useful when you want to iterate over multiple matched lists with one loop:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0):

Django Template Language provides you a way to do this...

```
{% for item in listModels %} 
 {{ forloop.counter }} 

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I will bring the value of the counter

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like I did the following:

```
{{ listModelsData|lookup:i|lookAttribute:"author" }} -// this equal listModelsData[i].author - this code in python 

@register.filter
def lookAttribute (d, token):
     return getattr (d, token)
```