# Use template tag (in HTML ) in view as a variable

Tags: django, django-views

I'm creating a web page on Django,
I want to create next and previous post in the bottom of blog page.

is there any way to use a simple tag like {{post.title}} in HTML and refer it to view page to find the index of current post ?

Comment: Hi @nima-pm .... Do you mean : you want to go to next/previous post where you are in page of current post ?

Comment: Hi @omarahmed , yes

Comment: See this answer ... hope it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795907/how-to-access-the-next-and-the-previous-elements-in-a-django-template-forloop

Answer (score 0):

This is where you should use [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/). If you are using DRF you might need [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) pagination.