# How to set href value by list with forloop.counter0 as index?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am passing list called 'list' to view and i want to create links with href attribute as value of list element iterated by `forloop.counter0`.

As far as I know getting list element requires such code :

```
{{ list.0 }}
```

But how can I iterate with `forloop.counter0` values?

What I do is something like this :

```
{% for name in names %}
    <tr>
         <a href="/foo/bar/{{ list.forloop.counter0 }}">
            {{ name }}
         </a>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But that doesnt apply any value and I tried with some more bracketting, but no succes.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list item dynamically in django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: OK, thanks for the clarification. I'd suggest a custom templatetag.

Create a `yourapp/templatetags/` dir. In that, create a blank file named `__init__.py` (this is required for Django to acknowledge the folder) and a file called `custom_tags.py`.

In `custom_tags.py` create a tag like so:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter('list_index')
def list_index(mylist,index): 
    return mylist[index]
```

Not in your template, add to the top:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

to import/initialize the library.

Now you can use this tag like so:

```
<a href="/foo/bar/{% list_index list forloop.counter0 %}">
```

to retrieve the item from your `list` at index provided by forloop.counter0.

Quick note - `list` is in the Python standard library, so never use it as a variable name (just in case this is mirroring your code).

Comment: I think that what the OP asks is the syntax to retrieve `list[forloop.counter0]` in a template.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses Yes, that's what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @JacekKozakowski Your question has already an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates).

Comment: Thanks for help guys.