# Django indexing in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following section in my template where I make use of indexing my query set to access its fields. I know this can be done without indexing but I am trying whether this can be done by indexing. `confirmed_length` is a list which is `[0]` and `confirmed_bookings` is the `query_set`

```
    {% for i in confirmed_length %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ confirmed_bookings.0.booking_id }}</th>
            <td>{{ i }}</td>
            <td>{{ confirmed_bookings.0.booking_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ confirmed_bookings.i.room_id }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

where `{{ i }}` shows 0 but nothing shows for others except
`{{ confirmed_bookings.0.booking_date }}` and `{{ confirmed_bookings.0.booking_id }}`. Indexing with `0` shows me the details  but indexing with `i` (where `i` is an integer and its value is 0) does not show anything.

Comment: That will not work. You have at least 2 options: 1. Use the [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/) template engine or 2. Implement your own [template filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list item dynamically in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates)

Comment: That won't work because when you write `{{ confirmed_bookings.i }}`, Django doesn't take the value of `i` from the loop. Instead it checks if `confirmed_bookings` has an attribute named `i`. Or if `confirmed_bookings` is a dict, does it have a key named `i`. When both the checks fail, Django renders nothing. *Source: [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)*