# Django - printing multiple passed lists from views.py

Tags: python, django

I have 4 lists with the same length and would like to pass all of them to the html page.

views.py

```
return render(request, 'result.html', {'listA':listA, 'listB':listB,  'listC':listC, 'listD':listD})
```

And here is the code when I tried with Flask.

app.py

```
return render_template('result.html', listA = listA, listB = listB, listC = listC, listD = listD)
```

Below is the code in the template file; with Flask, it prints out the table without any problems, but it doesn't seem to work with Django.
How should I fix my code?

result.html

```
{% for i in listA %}
<tr>
<th> {{ listA[loop.index] }} </th>
<td> {{ listB[loop.index] }} </td>
<td> {{ listC[loop.index] }} </td>
<td> {{ listD[loop.index] }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What error do you get ? Please post your traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list item dynamically in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates)

Comment: Here's the error I got:  Could not parse the remainder: '[loop.index]' from 'listA[loop.index]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a custom [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) for implementing lookup, because django does not provide one for you.
and then use django template engine [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for getting `forloop.counter0`

First create `templatetags` directory with `__init__.py` inside your app folder. Lets assume your app is called `polls` folder structure will look like this:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        lookup.py
    views.py
```

After write lookup code which goes inside `lookup.py`:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def lookup(d, key):
    return d[key]
```

And finlly use it in template file:

```
{% load lookup %}
...
{% for i in listA %}
    <tr>
        <th> {{ listA|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </th>
        <td> {{ listB|lookup:forloop.counter0 }}</td>
        <td> {{ listC|lookup:forloop.counter0 }}</td>
        <td> {{ listD|lookup:forloop.counter0 }}</td>
    </tr>
{%  endfor %}
...
```

- [Ref 1 - Get list item dynamically in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates)
- [Ref 2 - Custom template tag example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493001/1448424)
- [Ref 3 - Django templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout)
- [Ref 4 - Django template for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: i think this question is duplicate of (get-list-item)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates]

Comment: I got an error of   " Invalid filter: 'lookup' "   I'll read the django documentation first thank you!

Comment: @Tsao check out Ref 2, seems a problem of registering `lookup` template tag.

Comment: @demonno So I added
 'builtins': [
                '[[projectname]].filter.lookup',], 

to my TEMPLATES

but there's an error : "Invalid template library specified."

Comment: @Tsao see proper location for template tag `lookup` code in the updated answer.