# Loop list of list item dynamically in Django templates

Tags: python, django

I have list in a list that look like this :

```
clientList = [['Client 1', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'], ['Client 2', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'], ['Client 3', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes']]
```

I need to call the list in the template dynamically as below

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for c in clientList %}
    <td>{{c}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  <tr>
<table>
```

But it doesn't work because it looks like this:

[image: image of output]

And I also can't loop it using the method `{{c.0}}, {{c.1}}, {{c.3}}, {{c.4}}` because the list will change according to how many clients are selected. So I need to loop it dynamically.

I tried to use the method [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates) but it didn't work because I kept getting the error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: What is your expected output? Also why can't you use the `{{ c.0 }}` syntax? It has nothing to do with the number of clients.

Comment: @Selcuk He can't use `{{ c.0 }}` because he doesn't know how many elements `c` has.  Some might have 3, some might have 4, etc.

Comment: @JohnGordon Well, you might be right but that's not how I originally read the question: _"the list will change according to how many client are selected"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below. as you said, theres's a list inside a list. You did loop through the first list but forgot the second one.

```
    <table>
     <tr>
       {% for c in clientList %}
       {% for a in c %}
       <td>{{a}}</td>
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
     <tr>
    <table>
```