# Using an object attribute when accessing element in array in Django Template Python

Tags: python, django, templates

So basically in my Django template I'm passing in two things from my view.

1. a Django model object Plan which is defined like:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    class Sport(models.IntegerChoices):
        RUN = 1, "RUNNING"
        CYC = 2, "CYCLING"
        SWM = 3, "SWIMMING"

    sport = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=Sport.choices,
        default=Sport.RUN
    )

    start_date = models.DateField("Starting Date")
    end_date = models.DateField("End Date")
    weeks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and
2. an array of arrays of strava activities pulled from an API, `activity_list` which is formatted so `activity_list[i][j]` would return week i's activity on day j.

In my template, I need to access `activity_list` dynamically whilst looping through the week numbers in the plan. My first attempt was to do something like `ativity_list.week.number.0` to access the Monday of the week we're on, but as expected Django treats `week.number` as a literal instead of replacing it with the number "0" or "3" or whatever.

I'm really stuck on this so any help would be much appreciated, either with an ad-hoc fix or a way to refactor my models to make this feasible.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not really follwoing, what is `activity_list` (this does not seem te be provided in your model). Can you share a sample data of `activity_list`, and what you want to render in the template.

Answer (score 0):

So this is actually the same question as this:
[Get list item dynamically in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948430/get-list-item-dynamically-in-django-templates)

Basically use a filter like

```
@register.filter
def lookup(d, key):
    return d[key]
```

and then use `{% with lookup_result=mylist|lookup:x %}{{lookup_result.first_name}}{% endwith %}`

Comment: Please *don't* perform lookups in the template: Django's template engine deliberately did *not* implement this, since people tend to use it to move business logic to the template instead of the view.